# How do you ensure your workers live near their jobs?

Tags: banished

I've been playing off and on for a bit. I fully understand the "re-assign all" concept, and have used it many times before. Maybe I didn't really scrutinize hard enough in the past, but this time I tried using the pathing tool to see where my workers were taking up residence after reassigning. For some reason I have workers either choosing locations WAY out of the way (I had a few fishers/foresters choosing to live in areas that made no sense), or apparently choosing a "close by" job, only to link to a location far away (Such as fishers next to fishery A working at fishery B which is really far away, and the ones next to fishery B working at fishery A, again, being really far away).

I've toggled jobs and done as much as I know to try and remedy this, but I keep having this problem. I'm really discouraged from playing because of this, as I already felt that the "manual reassignment" was a ridiculous waste of time micromanaging. Now I see that it doesn't even work properly.

To note, I've made sure that I've had at least 1 house for every 2 workers I intend to have at a job. I've accounted for the fact that sometimes a house is inhabited by 1 person. In my situation, laborers MUCH closer to the target profession are being overlooked when the jobs are assigned.

One thing I've considered is that maybe assigned citizens are taken from their ACTUAL proximity to the job site, instead of their home? It seems pretty likely that the professions are consolidated, instead of each building having individual staffing logic, considering the nonsensical mix-up of my fisheries.

Has anyone else had a problem with this? Is this game even being updated anymore? It's a great game, with such a seemingly minor flaw in AI, or at least a lack of ensuring that bad AI can be effectively micromanaged. It would be a shame if this is as good as it gets.

Comment: @Philipp Debatable. And, if we are closing one as a dupe, this one's higher quality.

Comment: @Studoku The question might be higher quality, but if it's a dupe, it's the answers that matter.  Since this one has none, that disqualifies it from being a dupe target.